# Why use __unicode__(self) method for django 1.7+?

Tags: python, django, migration

I'm brand new with django and sql.  A tutorial I'm going through puts `def __unicode__(self)` on every models class?  here's the reference to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#unicode) But even after reading I still do not understand whats the purpose?

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Task(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the description in the documentation?  It seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: So whereever you use `unicode(instance)` or `{{ instance }}` in a template, that method is called, because just using `__str__` wouldn't work to produce Unicode. What parts of that *specifically* do you have problems with?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just didn't know how the models store data.  I guess that def converts the stored model data to unicode for the front end templates?

Comment: @MatthewHarwood: Whenever you need a unicode string representation for the object, you can use `unicode(object)` and that method is called. Its responsibility is to simply return a `unicode` value that nicely represents that object. It is used in the admin interface, for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idea is when you print {{Project}} you get essentially just get a bunch of garbage that isn't really informative.

```
def __Unicode__(self):
```

This defines what you print so {{Project}} would display the description of the object. Which is much more useful, TO YOU.

Comment: awesome so def __unicode__(self): will convert the models to unicode for the templates correct?

Comment: yes, but be aware that you cannot compare them ... for example {{project.description}} != {{project}} even though {{project}} will display the exact same string as {{project.description}}

Comment: @xElsa: sure you can; if `__unicode__` returns `self.description` then you have the *exact same Unicode object*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Except, you're not comparing the Unicode object. It just appears that you are. You are in fact comparing an object to a string.

Comment: @xElsa: right, but `unicode(project) == project.description` still.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're absolutely right about that.

Comment: https://youtu.be/ZGZB7hzybhE?list=PLEsfXFp6DpzRcd-q4vR5qAgOZUuz8041S&t=501 found this lol he explains it really poorly